# MYSQL Use OR in Left Join condition?

Tags: mysql

I'm not entirely sure that what I'm trying to do is possible.  Can you use an OR in the condition of a left join?  I start from my users table and then it can either go from week_meal to meal (adding a meal they do not own to their weekly meal plan) or straight to meal (a meal they own).  That part appears to be working, but when I include mta.meal_to_add_id in the select, it incorrectly pulls in meals that do NOT meet the criteria in the LEFT JOIN to meal_to_add.

Fiddle with structure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bd9c4

```
  SELECT DISTINCT m.*, o.username as owner,i.*, mta.meal_to_add_id, follow_id
    FROM webusers wu
LEFT JOIN week_meal wm ON wu.id=wm.user_id
LEFT JOIN meal m ON (wu.id=m.user_id OR wm.meal_id=m.meal_id)
LEFT JOIN webusers o ON m.user_id=o.id
LEFT JOIN meal_to_add mta ON 
    ((wm.user_id = mta.user_id AND wm.meal_id=mta.meal_id) 
     OR (m.user_id=mta.user_id AND m.meal_id=mta.meal_id))
     JOIN ingredient i ON m.meal_id = i.meal_id
LEFT JOIN follow f ON
 m.user_id!=wu.id AND
m.user_id=f.followed_webuser_id
 AND wu.id=f.followee_webuser_id
   WHERE wu.id=5 AND m.meal_id in (138)
ORDER BY m.meal, i.ingredient_id
```

OUTPUT:  It should be just like this only including the field for mta.meal_to_add_id, which in this case should be NULL for all rows (18)

[Sample Results](http://dev.yearlongmealplan.com/output.csv)

Comment: Post some sample data set with your expected result set

Comment: First, try to use `SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN DISTINCT ...`. The `STRAIGHT_JOIN` flag might fix the issue.

Comment: @Havenard http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bd9c4  I think i did that right?  the fiddle has the structure and i'm going to upload a pdf of the output.  sorry, i'm not sure the best way of doing all of this

Comment: @Havenard tried STRAIGHT_JOIN, but the query is still incorrectly joining to meal_to_add

Comment: Add some data too and the query to the right.

Comment: Just as a personal note, I often find ORs in LEFT JOINs very confusing, but that doesn't mean that they're not perfectly legitimate.

Comment: Folks, thanks for all of your help.  I decided to just use two simple selects with a UNION.  It's working much better, is fast, and is clear.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of your question: Yes, you can use an `OR` clause in a `LEFT JOIN`.

As for the second part, in plain words, this is what the query seems to say:

Join 'week meals' to users on the user id. Join meals to users on that same user id **OR** join meals to users on the meal id. Assume now that we have some matching meal/user combinations, where some meal rows are matched on user, and others are matched on the meal id.

Next, join webusers to meals again. Now we have meal rows possibly matching two sets of users. So when mta tries to match meals, it is matching two possible sets of meal/user combinations.

My practice in cases like this is to break up the query into two queries and put the intermediate results in a temp table (using MEMORY engine), then select from that.